# property auth doesn't exist on type AngularFireAuth : cannot find name 'auth' (error: T2304)

Tags: angular, authentication

I have an issue, implementing "Firebase authentication with Google" in my angular 8 app. It seems that "auth" property is not at all supported working since @angular/fire's version 6.0.0 !!!

Here are my dependencies :

"@angular/cdk": "^11.0.1",
"@angular/fire": "^6.1.4",
"firebase": "^8.1.2",

My Login service : (login.service.ts) :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
// import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class LoginService {

  constructor(
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, // Inject Firebase auth service
  ) { }

  // Sign in with Google
  GoogleAuth() {
    return this.AuthLogin(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }  

  // Auth logic to run auth providers
  AuthLogin(provider: any) {
    return this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then((result: any) => {
        console.log('You have been successfully logged in!')
    }).catch((error: any) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
  }

}
```

My login.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginService } from '../../services/login.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public loginService: LoginService) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

My login.component.html :

```
<button mat-raised-button  (click)="LoginService.GoogleAuth()" color="primary" >Login with Google</button>
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue ? Thanks for you help

Answer (score 2):

Install firebase

```
npm i firebase --save
```

Import firebase as:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

and then use it as,

```
return firebase.auth().signInWithPopup((new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have performed all your steps but unfortunately I still have an error on "auth" in (new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()).                                                                              
Error message in the terminal :                                                                     
error TS2339: Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/var/www/html/project-firebase/node_modules/firebase/index")'.

48     return this.AuthLogin(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
                                          ~~~~

Comment: Have you tried with removing node_modules folder and installing it again using npm i?

Comment: I think instead this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(provider) use firebase.auth().signInWithPopup((new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())); This syntax is working at my side.

Comment: Hi thank you for your comments. I solve this issu by downloading my "@angular/fire": version from "^6.1.4" to "^5.4.2"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, specifically this part:

```js
 // Sign in with Google
  GoogleAuth() {
    return this.AuthLogin(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }
```

I resolved it by following the instructions here:
https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md

In short, I removed the `{ auth }` import (like you did), and imported `firebase` instead:

```js
// import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

Now you can transform the above part of the code as follows:

```js
  // Sign in with Google
  GoogleAuth() {
    return this.AuthLogin(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }
```

> Keep in mind that the firebase import should be `import firebase from 'firebase/app';`, and not `import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';` - but I don't really know why.